# Azure Service Bus thrown exceptions cluttering debug output

Tags: nservicebus, azureservicebus

I'm running Azure Service Bus as a transport with NServiceBus. In my Visual Studio Output window, I am getting tons of exceptions thrown. They don't appear to actually be causing any issues with the system, everything works fine. They fire off every 25-30 seconds, so as you can imagine, this really clutters my output log and makes it difficult to read.

This is a sample of what gets printed every 30 seconds or so. This is only a small section of the total lines, roughly about 50-70 lines of FaultException and TimeoutExceptions in no particular order :

> Exception thrown: 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException'1' in Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll
>
> Exception thrown: 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException1' in Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll
>
> Exception thrown: 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException1' in Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll
>
> Exception thrown: 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException1' in Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll
>
> Exception thrown: 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException1' in Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll
>
> Exception thrown: 'System.TimeoutException' in Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by checking "Enable Just My Code" in Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General.

Comment: Could also raise an issue for the future client here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet

Comment: It can be a normal occurrence for Service Bus to throw exceptions without them surfacing to user code. For instance, an exception can be thrown and caught, causing a retry. If you wanted to continue to debug Service Bus code, but ignore these errors, you could also ignore that exception type in VS. Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings -> Common Language Runtime Exceptions -> System.ServiceModel.FaultException